# XPATH preceding node

Tags: c#, xpath

I have following XML:

**XML**

```
 <PatientDetailsXML>             
 <PList> 
           <PName type="Patient">    // node [i] = 0 
        <properties>
            <Room bedType="Auto" />
            <PName title="Joe Beom" PId="1234">
                <Details>
                    <classification classification="paymenttype" category="Wallet" />
                    <classification classification="Humor" category="1" />
                    <classification classification="Food" category="Fruit" />
                </Details>
            </PName>
            </properties>
        <childEvents>
        </childEvents>
    </PName>
            <PName type="Patient"> // node[i] =1
        <properties>
            <Room bedType="Auto" />
            <PName title="John Bair" PId="4567">
                <Details>
                    <classification classification="paymenttype" category="Wallet" />
                    <classification classification="Humor" category="2" />
                    <classification classification="Food" category="Fruit" />
                </Details>
            </PName>
            </properties>
        <childEvents>
        </childEvents>
    </PName>

            <PName type="Patient"> // node[i] = 2
        <properties>
            <Room bedType="Auto" />
            <PName title="Bairstow" PId="1234">
                <Details>
                    <classification classification="paymenttype" category="CreditCard" />
                    <classification classification="Humor" category="1" />
                    <classification classification="Food" category="Vegetables" />
                </Details>
            </PName>
            </properties>
        <childEvents>
        </childEvents>
    </PName>
```

When I'm at `node[0]`, i'm doing a search for `classification='paymenttype'` and `category ='CreditCard'`, I find the 3rd item node[i] = 2

```
  var next = currNode.SelectSingleNode(@"following::classifications/classification[@classification='paymenttype'and @category ='CreditCard'] /ancestor::PName/@title");  // This gives me the title `Bairstow`
```

Now I need to jump to my previous node where `classification='paymenttype'and @category ='CreditCard'`.

```
var previous = next.SelectSingleNode(@"preceding::classifications/classification[@classification='paymenttype'and @category ='CreditCard']/ancestor::event"); 
// this doesn't seem to work
```

**CODE**

```
var query = @"//PList/PName[.//PName/classifications/classification[@classification='paymenttype' and @category='Wallet']]";
var nodes = docs.SelectNodes(query).OfType<XmlNode>().ToArray();
XmlNodeList nodeList = docs.SelectNodes(query);


 for (int i = 0; i < nodes.Count(); i++)
{

  //do something
  //jump to method to do something else 

   string testPayment = Externals.Next(nodes[i]);

}

public static string Next(XMLNode currNode)
{
  var next = currNode.SelectSingleNode(@"following::classifications/classification[@classification='Humor'and @category ='1'] /ancestor::PName/@title");  
 // This gives me the title `Bairstow`

// Now I need to select the title of the previous node e.g.John Bair

var previous = next.SelectSingleNode(@"preceding::classifications/classification[@classification='paymenttype'and @category ='CreditCard']/ancestor::event");  
// this is not pointing to the node with title JohnBair

}
```

Comment: Just select under `currNode`, not `next`.

Comment: no that doesn't work. I need to jump from the next to the previous. because I have already moved out from the currNode by doing a search in next. Now my aim is to move back from the next

Comment: It's not quite so. `currNode` is not modified when you do SelectSingleNode. You can do any number of selections from this one node and it still be there.

Comment: I have tried this already and when I do a preceding it goes back to node[0]. It seems like when I call `Externals.Next(nodes[i])`, it only exposes node[I] to the method `Next`. And not all nodes. That's why when I do preceding it goes back to node[0].

Comment: I tried also a `.PreviousSibling`. It returns me to the same node[0].

Comment: I wonder what is the reason to rely on an order of nodes within the same level...

Comment: its a requirement.